# Key Down not working in listView

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

It is my second day doing c#...don't judge please. I have read other threads but they did not help.

I have this code:

```
private void listView1_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.KeyCode == Keys.Delete)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("aa");
    }
}
```

which is not working.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: is the event wired up on the listView control?

Comment: Are you actually binding the event to listView1 or did you manually create that method?

Comment: I did it manually...how do I actually bind the event to listView1?

Comment: Also, does the ListView have input focus?

Comment: try to use Window.Current.CoreWindow.KeyDown

Comment: Somewhere on creation of your listbox either in the constructor or the designer you would need to put listView1.KeyDown += listView1_KeyDown;

Comment: @Yanshof seems WinForms app not WPF. I'm very sure is problem with keyboard focus. Check it.

Comment: @JarrettRobertson I put that in form load method and it worked. If could put that as an answer so I could give you the credit

Comment: You __should__ have created the stub for the above code by going the the properties-events-tab(with the flash) and there seeking the event and double-clicking it. In this way the event stub is created and in the designer.cs file also wired up. Adding the wiring-code to the constructor is __not__ really a good idea!

Comment: @GrantWinney that is a much cleaner way IMHO, Thank you very much

Comment: Please research your question before you ask for help.  A good Google query is "c# how to add an event handler".  The 2nd hit tells you everything you need to know.

Comment: @HansPassant, I actually did research first. I found the code so I though manually typing them would do the trick. Excuse the noob please. Note taken

Comment: @JohnyStark also for a future reference, try to avoid the phrase "it's not working".  You can always provide a better context, and you'll get a much more positive reception here.  For example, something as simple as "I am unable to reach this code when I press delete in the listBox" is 100x better

Comment: @Jonesy thank you for your advice. I really gladful for that. Others would just downvote the question. I will keep that in mind

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is that you haven't told the ListView to actually use the event. To do this you have to assign the method to the required event. there are two ways to do this. Either select the ListView and open the Properties tab go to events and double click on the one you want. (Visual studio will automatically put the event out for you). Or in the constructor of the form or elsewhere you can manually assign it. In your case it would look like...

```
listView1.KeyDown += listView1_KeyDown;
```

Note you don't have to use a name similar to what visual studio would automatically produce. You can name your method whatever you want as long as the method signature matches the event. This is nice if you have multiple list boxes and want to use the same method to handle all of them. For example you could do something like.

```
listView2.KeyDown += listView1_KeyDown;
```

I suggest reading up on how events work in c#.